# In my Android app,how do I move the images from their position?

Tags: android, android-canvas

I have a class Panel which overrides onDraw() method as below.I have two images mentioned in canvas.drawBitmap(),as of now their position is fixed. Is it possible for me to move these two images from bottom to top on my emulator? Code is:

```
class Panel extends View {
    public Panel(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        Bitmap image1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.btnpre);
        canvas.drawColor(Color.CYAN);
        canvas.drawBitmap(Image1, 10, 10, null);
        Bitmap Image2 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.btnpre);
        canvas.drawBitmap(Image2, 100, 100, null);

    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re-write your code like this `canvas.drawBitmap(Image1, x, y, null);`.

And write a thread to change the value of `x` or `y` over time.

Once you change the value of `x` or `y`, please call `invalidate` in your Panel.java to redraw the view.

Comment: If you don't mind could you please elaborate with the code.I tried in vain

Answer (score 0):

use variables in onDraw call for values of x,y where you want to draw. I modified your code to redraw itself to new coordinates after 10 seconds of first draw call. It will give you an idea to use variables  inside draw call to dynamically change where you draw. Hope I have answered your question

```
class Panel extends View {
    public Panel(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    Handler handler = new Handler() {
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            x1 = 20;
            y1 = 20;

            x2 = 120;
            y2 = 120;
            invalidate();
        }
    }
    private int x1 = 10;
    private int y1 = 10;

    private int x2 = 100;
    private int y2 = 100;
    private boolean drawAfterTenSecs = false;


    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        Bitmap image1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.btnpre);
        canvas.drawColor(Color.CYAN);
        canvas.drawBitmap(Image1, x1, y1, null);
        Bitmap Image2 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.btnpre);
        canvas.drawBitmap(Image2, x2, y2, null);
        if(!drawAfterTenSecs) {
            handler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed (-1, 10000)
            drawAfterTenSecs = true;
        }
    }

 }
```

Comment: I used your code.It works fine and moves only one step i.e it jumps from the initial position to the final position.I want them to move continuously between the positions mentioned.How would you do that?

Comment: it depends on your need..i just tried to show case how you can control the variables....if you want a continuous thing..you can call sendEmptyMessageDelayed in the handleMessage call ?